# Valid Mapbox Token is required but I don't work

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, access-token, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I try to set up an react app with an integrated map of mapbox.
When I start the app, it says that the access token isn't valid. But I used the public token on the website.

```
VM68 react_devtools_backend.js:4061 Error: **A valid Mapbox access token is required to use Mapbox GL JS. To create an account or a new access token, visit https://account.mapbox.com/**
    at $t.errorCb (vendors-node_modules_mapbox-gl_dist_mapbox-gl_js.chunk.js:32679:240)
    at $t.getSessionAPI (vendors-node_modules_mapbox-gl_dist_mapbox-gl_js.chunk.js:900:22)
    at Map._authenticate (vendors-node_modules_mapbox-gl_dist_mapbox-gl_js.chunk.js:32676:13)
    at Map._render (vendors-node_modules_mapbox-gl_dist_mapbox-gl_js.chunk.js:32645:91)
    at Map.map._render (bundle.js:34693:17)
    at vendors-node_modules_mapbox-gl_dist_mapbox-gl_js.chunk.js:32737:73
overrideMethod @ VM68 react_devtools_backend.js:4061
onError @ bundle.js:33707
Mapbox._onEvent @ bundle.js:34564
fire @ vendors-node_modules_mapbox-gl_dist_mapbox-gl_js.chunk.js:1203
_fireEvent @ bundle.js:34996
(anonymous) @ vendors-node_modules_mapbox-gl_dist_mapbox-gl_js.chunk.js:32679
getSessionAPI @ vendors-node_modules_mapbox-gl_dist_mapbox-gl_js.chunk.js:900
_authenticate @ vendors-node_modules_mapbox-gl_dist_mapbox-gl_js.chunk.js:32676
_render @ vendors-node_modules_mapbox-gl_dist_mapbox-gl_js.chunk.js:32645
map._render @ bundle.js:34693
(anonymous) @ vendors-node_modules_mapbox-gl_dist_mapbox-gl_js.chunk.js:32737
```

I created an .env.local and connected it with my App.js. So I don't understand why this is not working. Here is my App.js:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import ReactMapGL from "react-map-gl";



export default function App() {
  const [viewport,setViewport] = useState ({
    longitude:-9.993682,
    latitude: 53.551086,
    zoom: 9,
    width: '100vw',
    height: '100 vh',
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <ReactMapGL
        {...viewport} mapboxApiAccessToken= {process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN}>
      </ReactMapGL>
    </div>
  );
}
```

On the website happens only one thing: A little grey square that hovers on click but I was supposed to show a map...

Anyone here who can help?

This is my .env.local:

```
REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN="pk.eyJ1IjoibG91c2NoYSIsImEiOiJja3pibmZsZTYwbm1nMm9zNmdpdmJwYW5lIn0.qy5kQf2SjEf4CkSg4JcY1Q"
```

This is my Folder structure:

[Folderstructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOkTL.png)

Comment: ReactMapGL accepts `mapboxAccessToken` as props or uses REACT_APP_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN as env var - [accessToken: props.mapboxAccessToken || getAccessTokenFromEnv() || null](https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl/blob/230fdaa60f0ce0284820637578633eae7c5afbd7/src/mapbox/mapbox.ts#L511)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide the `REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN` without the quotation marks: `REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN=pk.eyJ1IjoibG91c2NoYSIsImEiOiJja3pibmZsZTYwbm1nMm9zNmdpdmJwYW5lIn0.qy5kQf2SjEf4CkSg4JcY1Q`

For people not to abuse your Mapbox Token, you should consider generating a new one.

Comment: I tried both but this isn't working unfortunately...

Comment: As [tcconstantin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11760239/tcconstantin) rightfully pointed out, `mapboxApiAccessToken` should be `mapboxAccessToken`.

Comment: Does it work when using the Mapbox API token directly? 
`<ReactMapGL {...viewport} mapboxAccessToken="pk.eyJ1IjoibG91c2NoYSIsImEiOiJja3pibmZsZTYwbm1nMm9zNmdpdmJwYW5lIn0.qy5kQf2SjEf4CkSg4JcY1Q" />`

Comment: Yes it's working. Thank you!

Comment: And please remember to get a new `mapboxToken` so that no-one will abuse your account